# Problem with Update-BTNotification (Burnt Toast for Powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell, notifications, toast

I'm trying to make a small PowerShell program  to display a toast notification that will show me in real-time how a copy job is doing. For the moment I haven't coded origin/copy size-compare program, so it's supposed to go up of 1% every second.

```
$image = New-BTImage -Source "D:\Pictures\Profile image.png" -Crop Circle
$binding = @{
    text1 = "Downloading your files..."
    text2 = "Your files are being downloaded so they can be available offline."
    image = $image
    value = 0
}
$progress = New-BTProgressBar -Status "Downloading..." -Value $binding['value'] -Title "Download" -Verbose
New-BurntToastNotification -Text $binding['text1'], $binding['text2'] -AppLogo $binding['image'] -ProgressBar $progress -UniqueIdentifier "toast" -Verbose
foreach ($n in 1..100){
    $binding['value'] = $binding['value'] + 0.01
    $binding['text1'] = "hello"
    Write-Output $binding
    Update-BTNotification -UniqueIdentifier "toast" -DataBinding $binding -Verbose
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

But it doesn't seem to update ! The `-Verbose` doesn't show any error, and `Write-Output $binding` is clearly evidence `$bindings` is being updated every second...

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks for any answer,
Silloky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that works :

```
$progress = New-BTProgressBar -Title "Copying progress :" -Status "Downloading..." -Value 'value'
$image = New-BTImage -Source "$PSScriptRoot\icons\shell32_16739.ico" -Crop None
$button = New-BTButton -Dismiss -Content "OK"
$binding = @{
    value = 0
}
New-BurntToastNotification -Text "Downloading your files...", "Your files are being downloaded so they can be available offline." -DataBinding $binding -UniqueIdentifier "001" -ProgressBar $progress -AppLogo $image
Start-Sleep 3
foreach ($n in 1..100){
    Start-Sleep 0.5
    $binding['value'] = $binding['value'] + 0.02
    $null = Update-BTNotification -UniqueIdentifier "001" -DataBinding $binding
}
Remove-BTNotification -UniqueIdentifier "001"
New-BurntToastNotification -Text "Done !", "Your files are now available offline." -AppLogo $image -Button $button
```

Bye !